# Comment dit-on « like oil and water » en français ?

Tags: expressions

L'expression anglaise « like oil and water » s'emploie de façon hyperbolique pour insister sur le fait que deux personnes sont diamétralement opposées, comme les deux liquides immiscibles, ne se mettant d’accord sur absolument rien.

> Vous êtes ***comme l’eau et le vin***, tous les deux !

Je me demande si en français le mot « huile » peut céder la place au mot « vin », même si le vin se mélange en fait facilement avec l’eau... Ou peut-être que le contraste entre « eau » et « vin » fait allusion au fait que l’eau ne risque pas de provoquer l'ivresse, peu importe combien de bouteilles d'eau on boit ?

On dit d’ailleurs « wie Feuer und Wasser / comme le feu et l'eau » en allemand. Le feu passe logiquement pour son vis-à-vis, car les deux se volatilisent bel et bien, en se heurtant l'un contre l'autre. Ce que je trouve intéressant, c'est que ces trois expressions se chevauchent sur le même mot « eau ».

Comment: Ce que j'entends le plus souvent c'est "comme chien et chat".

Comment: It’s probably just a calque (perhaps tweaked to sound more appetizing and, imo, to actually make more sense than the original), but [“comme l’huile et le vinaigre”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22comme+huile+et+vinaigre%22+expression&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=expression+%22comme+l%27huile+et+le+vinaigre%22&tbm=bks) does get a dozen or so relevant hits on *Google* (unlike your suggestion, it seems to hold the “oil” and replaces instead the “water” with [sour] wine).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

L'expression « **comme l'eau et le vin** » est ambiguë, ces deux liquides étant parfaitement miscibles tout en ayant des caractéristiques très différentes (couleur, odeur, goût, effets secondaires…)

L'expression « **comme l'eau et le feu** » n'est pas, à ma connaissance, courante en France.

Comme l'a écrit Simon Déchamps dans un commentaire, « **comme chien et chat** » s'emploie bien plus souvent. Cette expression sous entend l'existence de conflits, disputes et désaccords entre deux personnes.

c.f TLFi:

> S'entendre, vivre comme [chien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chien) et chat (cf. chat1 II A 4). L'oncle et la tante vivaient en chien et chat animés l'un contre l'autre d'une antipathie instinctive (Courteline, La Vie de ménage,L'Escalier, 1890, p. 63).

...

> S'entendre, vivre comme chien et [chat](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chat). Se quereller, vivre en ennemis. Le temps n'est plus où la noblesse et la bourgeoisie vivaient entre elles comme chien et chat (Sandeau, Sacs et parchemins,1851, p. 17).

Sinon, il existe aussi l'expression « **[c'est le jour et la nuit](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/15468/c-est-le-jour-et-la-nuit/)** ».

[TLFi :](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jour)

> L'opposition jour/nuit illustre tout naturellement la loi des contraires. Dans ce livre (...) il y a tous les contraires, le doute et le dogme, le jour et la nuit, le coin sombre et le point lumineux, comme dans tout ce que nous voyons, comme dans tout ce que nous pensons en ce siècle (Hugo, Chants crépusc., 1835, préf., p. 5). Hortense ! ... Ah ! mon garçon, ne me parle pas d'elle ! La nuit et le jour avec l'autre (Zola, Bouton de rose, 1878, III, 3, p. 275).

Elle implique cependant le plus souvent un jugement, une préférence qui ne semble pas présents dans ***oil and water***.

Ex. [Marianne](https://www.marianne.net/debattons/editos/macron-le-pen-le-pire-n-est-jamais-certain):

> Marine Le Pen et Emmanuel Macron, c'est le jour et la nuit.

Comment: « C'est le jour et la nuit » et « comme chien et chat » se trouvent correspondre plus ou moins respectivement à « like day and night » et « fight like cats and dogs ». Ce n'est pourtant pas le cas pour « like oil and water ». Intéressant. :)

Answer (score 3):

Bonjour,

Je suis français et je me permets donc de vous répondre que l'expression "comme l'eau et le vin" n'existe pas. En effet, comme vous le dites, le vin et l'eau se mélangent très bien et donc cette expression n'aurait aucun sens.

Enfin, il faut savoir que seule l'expression "comme l'eau et le feu" est utilisée.

Comment: cf. les paroles de Starmania (["Le coup de téléphone"](http://www.celeri.net/starmania/paroles2.html#telephone)) : "Sadia et Cristal / Au premier regard / C'était comme le feu et l'eau."

Comment: @LukeSawczak Moi aussi, je me demande si on peut prendre des libertés avec l'ordre des mots.

Comment: Dans ce cas-ci oui. Mais en règle général non cela ne fonctionne pas.

Answer (score 2):

En partant de la [definition anglaise](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+like+oil+and+water):

> To be incompatible or unable to interact or coexist easily, as due to
>   fundamental differences in personality, opinions, beliefs

La traduction francaise est clairement:

> Vous êtes **comme chien et chat**, tous les deux !

voir (http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/597/etre-comme-chien-et-chat/)